# Реверсивное проксирование node.js apps в nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl, proxy, https

Добрый день !
Есть 10 ВМ , на них работают сайты , и реверсивное проксирование реализовано через nginx. Важно было иметь при этом ssl , поэтому в настройках nginx , а именно в файле /etc/nginx/nginx.conf это выглядит так:
(1.1.1.1 - IP ВМ , на которой работает сайт)

```
server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 listen 80 ;
  server_name domen.com;
ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/domen.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domen.com.key;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
reset_timedout_connection  on;
if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

     location ~* / {
        proxy_pass                      http://1.1.1.1:8080;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
     }       
     }
```

Появилась 11 ВМ , но на ней реализовать проксирование подобным образом , к сожалению, не вышло. Стоит только убрать SSL - и всё работает корректно. На 11 ВМ pm2 разворачивает два приложения (app1 и app2) node.js , первое - 11.11.11.11:8081 , и второе 11.11.11.11:8082. Запись для проксирования этих аппликаций выглядит так (нужно получить app1 на domen.com, app2 - domen.com/app2) :

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen 80 ;
server_name domen.com;
ssl_certificate              /etc/nginx/ssl/domen.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key          /etc/nginx/ssl/domen.com.key;
ssl_protocols                TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers                  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
location / {
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass             http://11.11.11.11:8081/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}       
location /app2/ {
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass             http://11.11.11.11:8082/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}                                                           
}
```

App1 - работает нормально , но вот app2 при https не может работать корректно , а при работе на http - всё отлично. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема ?

---

Проблема была в том, что нужен было отдельно проксировать socket.io

Comment: что значит «не может работать корректно»? уточните это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса.

Comment: поменяйте location правила местами. При заходе на app2 он вначале проходит первое правило и успокаивается.